# Using a 3G router to supply internet access

Tags: router, internet, 3g

I have a [TP-Link TL-MR3220](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-MR3220#spec)  router that distributes internet using 3G, but the situation has changed and I've got an ADSL connection.

So I bought an ADSL modem that has one Ethernet port. Now the question: Can I use the 3G router to distribute the internet?

Comment: if there is an WAN port in which an ethernet cable fits that's the place where you can insert your ethernet cable from the ADSL Moden into, then you can use the other ports on the router to connect other PC's to the internet, with - or without configuring the router. Can you please specify the model numbers of the devices and their manufacturers/brands?

Comment: well  my modem's model is TP-Link TL-MR3220

Comment: according to the specification http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-MR3220#spec there is a wan port @slhck!

Comment: guys i pushed the cable net in the wan port but still no internet :(

Comment: I think you need to go to the routers web page and enable DNS and configure some stuff, and select that the internet has to come from the WAN port instead of the 3G/4G network

Comment: Tell please about the ADSL device. Its model, does it supplies your pc with private address or you get public address at your PC, how PC is connected to the internet (if PPTP or PPPoE or what ever 'magic' is used?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://nl.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/TL-MR3220/index.htm

This is a simulator of your routers interface, so I can see what needs to be done.

What I'd select:

Network>Internet Acces> WAN ONLY

Then goto

Network>WAN> and refresh the settings, your router should now be able to transmit the internet data to other PC's from now on.

DHCP is enabled by default so this shouldn't be a problem.

Note: You can also use the Quick Setup Wizard which will guide you through the process of setting up an internet connection from the WAN port.